# How to migrate a domain from 1&1 IONOS to Vercel?

Tags: hosting, vercel, ionos

until today I was using a simple PHP website hosted on a server I bought to 1&1 IONOS a while ago. I also bought my domain there.

However, I rebuilt my website using `SvelteKit`, and I want to host it on Vercel. I followed the instructions to reconfigure the DNS :

on `mywebsite.fr`:

- `A` set to `76.76.21.21`

on `www.mywebsite.fr`:

- `CNAME` set to `cname.vercel-dns.com`

(No redirections).

I also kept the original one from Vercel: `mywebsite.vercel.app`.

Vercel is saying that the configurations are correctly set and that everything should work perfectly fine. However, here I am, with a problem. The top-level domain is not working (`mywebsite.fr`). It still uses the old `index.php` from the FTP server. I tried deleting the `index.php` file but now it shows a `403 Forbidden` error (apparently a visitor doesn't have the "authorisation" to access a file).

The only solution that I found is using a `.htaccess` at the root of my FTP server:

```
Redirect 307 / https://www.mywebsite.fr
```

For some reason, `www.mywebsite.fr` works perfectly fine (it shows the SvelteKit version of my website), and for an unknown reason, it automatically redirects to `mywebsite.fr` (I have no idea why, and such redirection doesn't come from Vercel). Apparently, I, or IONOS itself, configured a permanent redirection. Once a visitor accessed `www.mywebsite.fr` the top-level domain is working fine. I don't remember setting such redirection, it's been countless years.

To summarise, how do I transfer a domain, that I was previously using via an FTP server, to Vercel?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS cache or propagation issue. Check the website in your phone or another device. You can also use `dig A mywebsite.fr @1.1.1.1` to check the DNS record.

Comment: Well, I removed my ugly `.htaccess` file and now it seems to work... I don't know why but I tested another computer, and a friend tried the website on his phone, and it seems to be working just fine. I don't know why the problem got fixed on its own but I'm not going to complain ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did all those things in the morning, and the problems happened this morning, but at the evening it was working fine. At least, I think it's working. Maybe it was some sort of propagation issue and hidden DNS cache.